# ProgressDialog hasta que termine de cargarse una vista usando Thread

Tags: android, rss

Pues tengo una vista en la que cargo un **RSS** y me gustaría que saliera un `ProgressDialog` mientras carga.

Actualmente lo tengo puesto para que dure 3 segundos, pero quiero saber como ponerlo para que dure hasta que termine de cargarse la vista:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_noticias);
        TextView fuente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        String url = getResources().getString(R.string.rssUrl);
        final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = 
ProgressDialog.show(verNoticias.this, "Por favor espere ...",   "Cargando 
Informacion ...", true);
        ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        View vista;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
        fuente.setText("FUENTE: "+ url);
       CargarXmlTask tarea = new CargarXmlTask();
        tarea.execute(url);
    }
private class CargarXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            RssParserSax parser = new RssParserSax(params[0]);
// RssParserDom parser = new RssParserDom(params[0]);
            noticias = parser.parse();
            return true;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            System.out.println(noticias.toString());
            TextView txtResultado = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.textoNoticias);
//txtResultado.setText(noticias.toString());
            Noticia n;
            for(int i=0; i<noticias.size(); i++) {
                n = noticias.get(i);
                txtResultado.setText(
                        txtResultado.getText().toString() +
                                System.getProperty("line.separator") + 
n.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

        }
    }
```

La solucion que me ha servido ha sido la siguiente:

```
   public class verNoticias extends AppCompatActivity {
   **boolean bandera=true;**
    List<Noticia> noticias;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_noticias);
    TextView fuente = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texto);
    String url = getResources().getString(R.string.rssUrl);
    final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(verNoticias.this, "Por favor espere ...", "Cargando Informacion ...", true);
    ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        View vista;
        @Override
        public void run() {
           **while (bandera) {**
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            **}**
            ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).start();
    fuente.setText("FUENTE: "+ url);
    CargarXmlTask tarea = new CargarXmlTask();
    tarea.execute(url);

}

//Tarea Asíncrona para cargar un XML en segundo plano

private class CargarXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        RssParserSax parser = new RssParserSax(params[0]);
// RssParserDom parser = new RssParserDom(params[0]);
        noticias = parser.parse();
        bandera=false;
        **return bandera;**
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        System.out.println(noticias.toString());
        TextView txtResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoNoticias);
//txtResultado.setText(noticias.toString());
        Noticia n;
        for(int i=0; i<noticias.size(); i++) {
            n = noticias.get(i);
            txtResultado.setText(
                    txtResultado.getText().toString() +
                            System.getProperty("line.separator") + n.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Con vista a que te refieres? A la página?

Comment: A la activity nueva quiero decir.
En la activity principal hay un boton que te lleva a esta activity(en la que se ven noticias sacadas por RSS) y me gustaria que al abrirse esta activity(la de las noticias) saliera el progressDialog en lugar de 3seg como esta ahora, hasta que terminen de cargarse las noticias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es mantener tu actual estructura, puedes usar una bandera global así:

```
boolean bandera = true;
```

luego agregas en tu Thread esto:

```
while(bandera) {
   try {
     Thread.sleep(100);
   } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

luego en la parte de tu task donde terminas de cargar los datos, agregas:

```
 bandera = false;
```

Y con eso es suficiente... pero la manera más simple y creo idónea de hacerlo es quitando ese Thread y hacerlo con un Asynktask (suponiendo que eso es CargarXmlTask) desde la parte del onPostExcecute. Checa esto:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327369/how-can-i-dismiss-progressdialog-in-asynctask

También puedes usar un Semaphore. Checa acá:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Comment: pero así entraría en un bucle sin fin, puesto que mi task lo ejecuto fuera del thread, lo que conlleva que una vez entrado en el bucle que solo tiene el sleep no pueda salir, ya que la bandera se cambia fuera del mismo.

Comment: Gracias compañero, he conseguido solucionarlo.

Comment: Un gusto, ten en cuenta la respuesta de @Pablo Simon DiEstefano para tu futuro desarrollo. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

La manera ideal de mostrar el `ProgressDialog` para que se muestre mientras se está descargando el RSS y deje de mostrarse cuando finalice la carga del RSS es que utilices el `ProgressDialog` dentro del `AsyncTask`. Para ello tendrás que iniciar el `ProgressDialog` en el `onPreExecute()` y finalizar el `ProgressDialog` en el `onPostExecute()`, quedando tu `AsyncTask` de la siguiente forma:

```
private class CargarXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        pDialog.setMessage("Obteniendo datos");
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        RssParserSax parser = new RssParserSax(params[0]);
// RssParserDom parser = new RssParserDom(params[0]);
        noticias = parser.parse();
        return true;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        try{
            if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(noticias.toString());
        TextView txtResultado = (TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.textoNoticias);
//txtResultado.setText(noticias.toString());
        Noticia n;
        for(int i=0; i<noticias.size(); i++) {
             n = noticias.get(i);
             txtResultado.setText(
                        txtResultado.getText().toString() +
                                System.getProperty("line.separator") + 
n.toString() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
}
```

Por otra parte deberás quitar el ProgressDialog que tienes actualmente.

Answer (score 1):

Opino como @Joacer, aunque creo que no es necesario esto:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    pDialog = null;
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

En la clase desde la que ejecutas la llamada al Asynktask create una variable global Context y se la pasas al ProgressDialog, en el postExecute solo deberás hacer pDialog.dismiss(), te lo pongo muy por encima:

```
public class ClasePrincipal extends ActionBarActivity{
    Context cont = this;
    ProgressDailog pDialog;
    //Resto de cosas

    private class CargarXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(cont);
            pDialog.setMessage("Espere..."); //Las opciones que quieras
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            //Operaciones necesarias
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Operaciones necesarias
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: no me había dado cuenta que había puesto el `runOnUiThread`, lo he cogido de un app que tengo en la que el ProgressDialog lo tenia definido en la actividad en vez de en el Asynctask y se me ha olvidado quitarlo. Gracias por el apunte! Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Elimina la parte del `new Thread(new Runnable ...).start()`

Deberas cerrar el progressDialog cuando termines la tarea de cargado de noticias usando este código:

```
ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
```

Si la tarea es síncrona con ponerlo debajo de  `tarea.execute(url);`, aunque me da que es tarea asíncrona (asynctask).

En tal caso es un poco más complicado.

1- En tu CargarXMLTask debes crear una interfaz que funcionará como callback:

```
 public interface Callbacks {

        void onPreExecute();
        void onProgressUpdate(int progress);
        void onPostExecute(int result);
        void onCancelled();
    }
    private Callbacks mListener;
```

2- Tu actividad debería implementar este callback, añadiendo los métodos 4 métodos que metiste.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        CargarXMLTask.Callbacks
```

3- En tu tarea asíncrona tener el método onPostExecute modificado para que mediante el callback llame al método de la actividad:

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPostExecute(result);
        }
 }
```

4- Y ya en tu método onPostExecute de tu actividad haces el

```
 @Override
    public void onPostExecute(int result) {
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Nadie dijo que sería bonito.

Comment: La parte del Thread es estrictamente necesaria ya que es un requisito que me piden los profesores... gracias por la ayuda.